# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel - How to save Excel (Visible cells only) to CSV in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

Currently I can save Excel to CSV as code below.
However, it's save all data which is including invisible cells.

```
Dim excelApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
excelApplication = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
excelApplication.Visible = False
excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = False
workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(in_InputFilePath)
workbook.SaveAs(in_OutputFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV)
workbook.Close()
excelApplication.Quit()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApplication)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim excelApplication As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim workbook1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim workbook1worksheet1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Dim workbook1worksheet1range1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
Dim workbook2 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim workbook2worksheet1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
Dim workbook2worksheet1range1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
excelApplication = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
excelApplication.Visible = False
excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = False
workbook1 = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(in_InputFilePath)
workbook1worksheet1 = CType(workbook1.Sheets("Sheet1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
workbook1worksheet1.Select(Type.Missing)
workbook1worksheet1range1 = workbook1worksheet1.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Type.Missing)
workbook1worksheet1range1.Copy
workbook2 = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add()
workbook2worksheet1 = CType(workbook2.Sheets("Sheet1"), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
workbook2worksheet1range1 = workbook2worksheet1.Range("A1")
workbook2worksheet1range1.PasteSpecial()
workbook2.SaveAs(in_OutputFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV)
workbook2.Save()
workbook2.Close()
workbook1.Close()
excelApplication.Quit()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook2worksheet1range1)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook2worksheet1)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook2)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook1worksheet1range1)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook1worksheet1)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook1)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApplication)
```